# Have Flutter-based app suppress phone's NFC function for other apps

Tags: flutter, nfc

Building an app using Flutter that allows the user to manage various e-tickets in the form of barcodes, (like a QR-code). The barcodes will be used in public transport. The user will show the on-screen barcode to the barcode reader in the bus, or on an entrance gate.

These mentioned barcode readers also have an NFC reader.

The problem is that when the user shows the barcode, at the same time, the user checks in with the bank card, as set in Google/Apple Wallet. This event is referred to as 'card clash'.

For our app to work properly, this card clash must be prevented. Therefore, the phone's NFC-function must somehow be suppressed, while our e-ticket app is opened.

What I tried is to open an NFC-session with an empty callback method, hoping that our app will in this way keep the NFC function busy, so that Google/Apple Wallet will not work. (Code snippet below; this method would be called in main.dart as Initial Action).

```
Future suppressNfc() async {
  /**
   * The idea here was that an NfcSession was initiated, which would then call a callback 
   * method that's just empty. So that the NFC-function of the phone would be 'kept busy'
   * so to speak, so that Google Wallet and other apps cannot use it. This didn't work.
   */
  NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {});
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I work with Flutter Flow, but if necessary I'll implement a solution using Android Studio.